# How do Bayesian methods in machine learning help with the problem of limited data? Can this be used for image classification?

Tags: machine-learning, data, image-classification, bayesian

When reading about machine learning, I've often come across information stating that Bayesian methods in machine learning are effective when you only possess a limited amount of data. As someone who is planning to start learning machine learning, I was curious how it accomplishes this? Lastly, and more specifically, I was especially wondering how and/or if this can be applied to problems such as image classification, when there is a limited amount of data (limited number of images to train the algorithm on)?

Any textbook, research, or other references with regards to the latter would also be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, a major reason the Bayesian paradigm cam trump the frequentist one in small samples is because of the use of priors. If you use a relatively informative prior, you can get away with less data because information comes from both the data and the prior, as opposed to only coming from the data

Comment: @MattKaye Yes, I agree with this. I didn't really learn this until after I had posted this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discussion of Bayesian reasoning and its advantages over frequentist reasoning is very wide. I refer you to the book “Pattern recognition and machine learning” by Cristopher Bishop which is a great book on Bayesian reasoning.